# 4 DIGIT random number C++

Tags: c++

Im trying  to do 4 digit random number at the moment have this

```
class PasswordGuessingGame {
private:

    int number = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
public:

    int getNumber() {
        return number;    
    }

};
```

but get random number that doesn't make sense can anyone help me? I'm new into this.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly "doesn't make sense"?

Comment: What range do you want? `0 - 9999`? or `1000 - 9999`?

Comment: @Galik, i think he want numbers between 1000 to 9999 .

Comment: @Himanshu Maybe but `4 digit number` usually means [0-9999].

Comment: @Galik: that's a degenerate definition since then all 4 digit numbers are also 5 digit numbers, and so on, which is clearly absurd.

Comment: @lusito92, you need to write `number = rand() % 9000 + 1000;` in your `getNumber()` function to get different number everytime.

Comment: @Bathsheba If you want to generate a `4 digit` number without qualification then your number range is `0000 - 9999`. The number of filling zeros is *always* a matter for print formatting otherwise you could argue that `9999` (stored in an `int`) is really `0000009999`. That would mean **all** `int` values are larger than 4 digits.

Comment: @lusito92 Feel free to ansnwer questions at any time.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the new C++ Standard Library!

The best way is to use

```
#include <random>
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd()); // seed the Mersenne Twister generator
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1000, 9999); // define the range
```

Then, in your function, write

```
return dist(mt);
```

This will have vastly better statistical properties than the old `rand()`.

Your specific problem is caused by your storing a *single* drawing in your class member `number`, and repeatedly returning that.

Comment: thanks for your help but is there any way you can put it inside my class? not outside of my class?

Comment: Indeed, `rd`, `mt`, and `dist` all become members of your class; you can set them up in your constructor. You function becomes the one-liner I already give. Another (good) answer has provided you with a worked example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example for your case, using modern C++ random number generation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

unsigned seed = static_cast<size_t>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

class PasswordGuessingGame {
private:
    std::mt19937 random_engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> random_generator;

public:
    PasswordGuessingGame() :
        random_engine(seed),
        random_generator(1000, 9999)
    {
    }

    int getNumber() {
        return random_generator(random_engine);
    }

};

int main()
{
    PasswordGuessingGame game;
    std::cout << "Random value: " << game.getNumber() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```